# Ler informações de arquivo. txt utilizando Python

Tags: python, text

Boa noite!

Eu possuo um arquivo .txt que armazena uma estrutura de dados da seguinte forma:

```
índice: p1[x1, y1], p2[x2, y2], p3[x3, y3], p4[x4,y4]
```

Um exemplo de linhas do meu arquivo é:

```
1: p1 = [62.61, 79.47], p2 = [64.17, 75.43], p3 = [58.85, 72.5], p4 = [57.45, 76.6]
2: p1 = [64.17, 75.43], p2 = [68.63, 63.22], p3 = [63.59, 60.71], p4 = [58.85, 72.5]
```

Assim, eu gostaria de saber como posso extrair apenas os dados importantes do meu arquivo e armazená-los em variáveis, utilizando linguagem Python. No caso, os dados de interesse são os valores numéricos, que correspondem à coordenadas cartesianas.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda! :)

Comment: São 4 pontos por linha ? É você que controla o formato do arquivo ? Se sim então está a complicar algo que pode fazer bem simples com um csv por exemplo

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar expressões regulares para parsear essas linhas.

```
import re
with open('seu_arquivo.txt') as f:
    for linha in f:
        indice, restante = linha.split(':', 1)
        registro = {k: (float(v1), float(v2)) for k, v1, v2 in 
            re.findall(r'(\w+) = \[([\d.]+), ([\d.]+)\]', restante)}
        registro['indice'] = indice
        print(registro)
        # resultado.append(registro) # armazena em lista se precisar?
        # pode acessar as variaveis usando registro['p2'] etc
```

Rodando com o seu exemplo, saiu:

```
{'p1': (62.61, 79.47), 'p2': (64.17, 75.43), 
 'p3': (58.85, 72.5), 'p4': (57.45, 76.6), 'indice': '1'}

{'p1': (64.17, 75.43), 'p2': (68.63, 63.22), 
 'p3': (63.59, 60.71), 'p4': (58.85, 72.5), 'indice': '2'}
```